# SQL - How Can I Use Returned Table, and add INNER JOIN and WHERE Clause in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote a sql query, and it returned me following table:

```
TitleName TitleCount
 Title1    2
 Title2    1
```

I want to use this returned table again, for example, I want to INNER JOIN with another returned table, or use WHERE clause like:

```
WHERE TitleName='Title1'
```

I tried:

```
SELECT column_name FROM (returned_table) INNER JOIN (returned_table_2) ON ...
```

It doesn't work, it says that I'm using SELECT keyword twice.

Comment: you should post the query that *doesn't work*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, just use a `subquery`:

```
select *
from (returned_table) t
where titlename = 'Title1'
```

With that said, you should be able to add `where` criteria to your existing query to limit it to `Title1`.

Comment: OK, now it works. I forgot to add the alias. It should be like this:

`SELECT * FROM (returned_table) AS alias_name`